# $ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{2}{(x-1)\cdot(x^2-6x+10)}\,\mathrm{d}\,x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

how to approach such types of problems as improper integral?

> $$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{2}{(x-1)\cdot(x^2-6x+10)}\,\mathrm{d}\,x$$

is it also solve by complex theory integration?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @PrachiGauravShukla did you try [partial fraction decomposition](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B%28x-1%29%5Ccdot%28x%5E2-6x%2B10%29%7D)?

Comment: You don't need complex function theory. Just do a [partial fraction decomposition](https://www.sfu.ca/math-coursenotes/Math%20158%20Course%20Notes/sec_Rational_Functions.html) of the integrand

Comment: Different approaches work nice here. If you insist upon using complex integration - make a closed contour in the upper half-plane as @Troposphere recommended (adding a big radius $R$ counterclockwise and a small circle of radius $\epsilon$ clockwise around $x=1$). You get $\oint=I+\int_{\epsilon}+\int_R=2\pi{i}Res\frac{2}{(x-1)(x-3+i)(x-3-i)}|_{x=3+i}\Rightarrow$ $I=-\int_{\epsilon}+2\pi\frac{1}{2+i}$. As $\int_{\epsilon}$ is purely imaginary, taking the real part $I=2\pi\Re\frac{1}{2+i}=\frac{4\pi}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

You could try partial fraction decomposition as suggested in the comments, but that doesn't immediately look like progress -- it will split into integrals that are even more improper, since $\int \frac{A}{x-1}\,dx$ diverges towards $\pm\infty$ *in addition to* around the pole at $x=1$.

Contour integration, on the other hand, looks promising:

For some large $R$, integrate along a contour from $-R$ to $1-\varepsilon$, then a small semicircle around the pole to $1+\varepsilon$, then straight on to $+R$, and a large semicircle back to $-R$ through the upper half-plane.

What we really want is the sum of the straight parts as $R\to\infty$ and $\varepsilon\to 0^+$. However, since the magnitude of the integrand falls away as $|x|^{-3}$, the contribution of the *large* semicircle goes to $0$ a $R\to\infty$. And the contribution of the *small* semicircle will tend to a purely imaginary value (why?) when $\varepsilon$ is small.

You already know the answer is real, so what you're looking for must be the *real* part of the integral along a contour that goes around the pole at $x=3+i$, which you can find easily using residues.

Comment: Your divergence concerns are no obstacle to a partial-fractions solution. See e.g. my answer.

Comment: @J.G. I agree that it's at most a _surmountable_ obstacle. Still seems to me that the residue solution involves less actual calculation that can go wrong.

Comment: ...which is a far cry from "that hardly seems to be progress".

Comment: @J.G. Okay, I've toned that down.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\tfrac{2}{5(x-1)}-\tfrac{2(x-5)}{5(x^2-6x+10)}\right)dx=\left[\tfrac15\ln\tfrac{(x-1)^2}{x^2-6x+10}+\tfrac45\arctan(x-3)\right]_{-\infty}^\infty.$$As $x\to\pm\infty$, the numerator and denominator of $\tfrac{(x-1)^2}{x^2-6x+10}$ are both asymptotic to $x^2$, so the logarithm $\to\ln1=0$, and the integral is $\tfrac45(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-\tfrac{-\pi}{2})=\tfrac{4\pi}{5}$.

Comment: what happened about the singularity at 1?

Comment: @Q.Zhang Because the logarithm's argument has no real poles, the logarithm's branch cuts don't cause the same problems when integrating on $\Bbb R$ as you would get from e.g. trying the illegal argument $\int_{-1}^2\frac{dx}{x}=[\ln|x|]_{-1}^2=\ln2$.

Comment: The logarithm's argument still has a real _zero_ here, though. I think it's right that this ultimately doesn't invalidate the result (intuitively, because we back away from zero in the same direction as we approached it from), but it's a still a bit more subtle than it looks like here.

Comment: (... or more precisely because $\ln\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2-6x+10}$ has about the same value at $x=1-\varepsilon$ as at $x=1+\varepsilon$, so ignoring the zero will give us exactly the Cauchy principal value ... but that's the same observation that rescues $[\ln |x|]^2_{-1}$)

Comment: @Troposphere Or to put it another way, the *sign* of the argument doesn't change around $x=1$, so the fact that the most general antiderivative of $1/x$ is $\ln|x|+C$ with the locally constant function $C$ having different values either side of $x=0$ causes no problems here.